# Is it possible to run ZeroMQ on an Arduino

Tags: arduino, zeromq

I'm wondering, whether it is possible to communicate with an Arduino via ZeroMQ. I want to use the Arduino to control some equipment and want to have most of the application sit on a computer. For that it would be nice if the Arduino and the controller could communicate via zeromq and say a WiFi or Ethernet shield. Is that possible?

In particular, is it in principle possible, given the current chips on the Arduino boards, and has anybody had success in that direction?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don't think it will be easy to actually run the ZeroMQ library on an Arduino. The reason is that ZeroMQ is built on top of the POSIX or Windows networking APIs, which are not available on an Arduino.

What could be an option allowing you to use ZeroMQ on the host side, is to implement the (fairly trivial) [ZeroMQ Message Transport Protocol](http://rfc.zeromq.org/spec:13) on the Arduino and talk to ZeroMQ on the host this way.

Comment: I am trying to figure this out myself, but the spec linked above is tagged "retired".  I think this is actually the appropriate protocol: [ZMTP - ZeroMQ Message Transport Protocol](http://rfc.zeromq.org/spec:13).

Comment: It's worth generalized commenting -- try to limit the Arduino to lightweight message packets to a gateway/host PC, or message/logging service like Cosm.  

Let the Arduino notify something else, which in turn relays the message. This applies not only to the latest web standard for passing messages, but also for classic protocols like SMTP.